# Android Studio - ActivityClass::class.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a kotlin activity used as splashscreen to check if the user is already logged in using Google services or not. After awaiting 600ms it should create an intent to redirect the user on the LoginActivity or MainActivity using the **ActiviyClass::class.java**

For some reason Android studio marks "java" in red and tells "Unresolved reference: java", where did i mess up?

Code:

```
 var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)

        if(!isLoggedIn()){
            intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        }
```

[Explanatory image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMLJi.png)

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate Cache & Restart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly these type of issues are related to tool that you are using i.e Android studio. I have copied your code and pasted in my project and its working perfect.

Please look screen shot attached.

[image]

**Possible solution :**

1- Try invalidate cache and restart your Android studio. I am attaching screen shot of place where you can find this option.

[image]

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try invalidate cache & restart, or check project's java dependency

Answer (score 0):

**1. Solution**

Looks like you are using Kotlin2Js. If you are using the idea to compile the code, make sure your project settings are set to Kotlin(JVM) and not Kotlin Java Script.

if the above solution does not work then try to do the second solution

**2. Solution**

Try to invalidate caches

`goto -> File -> Invalidate caches -> click on Invalidate and Restart button`

Answer (score -1):

You directly start MainActivity before checking `!isLoggedIn()` condition. That's why you facing this error. I'm a java developer but I think the problem is here

make your code as below I changed.

```
        
        if(!isLoggedIn()){
            var intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        }
        else{
        var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Android studio suggests to simplify the code as shown in the code

Comment: The question is not related to syntax . Its about code is not visible to tool. To solve this issue we rebuild or clear cache and restart android studio.

Comment: @ZaeemSattar you have to read my answer carefully. I already mentioned in my answer that `I think the problem is here`. I'm not saying that my answer is the exact solution to that problem.

Comment: For these type of things you should only comment on question instead of answer because if naive developers read your answer he/she will get confused.

happy coding.